# Pyside/Pyqt5 dynamically adding and sorting items

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I have a simple user interface where I want to dynamically add frames and labels in a widget (as I will use these labels to transmit a video feed from my webcams).

In the following code I set a function where the user selects an integer which represents the number of labels(webcams) they want to see and then dynamically adds these labels& frames to the widget:

```
def loopCamFeed(self,n):
    if (n % 2) == 0:
        dividnd = n / 2
        for i in range(2):
            self.frame_12 = QFrame(self.ui.webcamWidget)
            self.frame_12.setObjectName(u"frame_12")
            self.frame_12.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
            self.frame_12.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
            self.horizontalLayout_14 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_12)
            self.horizontalLayout_14.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_14")
            for i in range(int(dividnd)):
                self.label_5 = QLabel("hello",self.frame_12)
                self.label_5.setObjectName(u"label_5")
                self.horizontalLayout_14.addWidget(self.label_5, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)
                self.ui.verticalLayout_15.addWidget(self.frame_12)
```

Which displays the labels as in the image below:

--By adding a value of 2:
[image]

--By adding a value of 4):

[image]

By adding a value of 8:
[image]

The challenge that I am facing is how to handle an odd number selection. For example, if a user selects 3 or 7 webcams/labels.

If a user selects 3 labels/webcams, I'd want to show one on the top frame and two at the bottom.

MAIN.PY (Where this piece of code was written):

```
from ui_interface import *
import sys
from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import *
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)
        self.show()

        

        #Expand Center Menu Widget
        self.ui.settingsBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.centerMenuContainer.expandMenu())
        self.ui.infoBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.centerMenuContainer.expandMenu())
        self.ui.helpBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.centerMenuContainer.expandMenu())

        #Close Center Menu Widget
        self.ui.closeCenterMenuButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.centerMenuContainer.collapseMenu())

        #Close Notification Menu Widget
        self.ui.closeNotificationBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.popUpNotificationContainer.collapseMenu())

        self.loopCamFeed(4)
    

    def ImageUpdateSlot(self, Image):
        self.ui.label_5.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(Image))

    def CancelFeed(self):
        self.worker1.stop()
    
    def startVideo(self):
        self.worker1 = Worker1()
        self.worker1.start()
        self.worker1.ImageUpdate.connect(self.ImageUpdateSlot)
    
    def loopCamFeed(self,n):
        if (n % 2) == 0:
            dividnd = n / 2
            for i in range(2):
                self.frame_12 = QFrame(self.ui.webcamWidget)
                self.frame_12.setObjectName(u"frame_12")
                self.frame_12.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame_12.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
                self.horizontalLayout_14 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_12)
                self.horizontalLayout_14.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_14")
                for i in range(int(dividnd)):
                    self.label_5 = QLabel("hello",self.frame_12)
                    self.label_5.setObjectName(u"label_5")
                    self.horizontalLayout_14.addWidget(self.label_5, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)
                    self.ui.verticalLayout_15.addWidget(self.frame_12)
        
 
class Worker1(QThread):
    ImageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.ThreadActive = True
        Capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self.ThreadActive:
            ret, frame = Capture.read()
            if ret:
                Image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                FlippedImage = cv2.flip(Image, 1)
                ConvertToQtFormat = QImage(FlippedImage.data, FlippedImage.shape[1], FlippedImage.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                Pic = ConvertToQtFormat.scaled(1200, 900, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.ImageUpdate.emit(Pic)

    def stop(self):
        self.ThreadActive = False
        self.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: For a layout like this, you should use a QGridLayout. Unfortunately, your code is very cryptic to provide you a valid answer: you're continuously overwriting instance attributes, you're referring to different objects (some created for `self`, others for `self.ui`, and you're also adding the same widgets to different layouts. It also seems like you're trying to edit a pyuic generated file (or mimicking its behavior, which is pointless).

Comment: @musicamante I shared the entire code for the main file. I assumed it would be understood that for the ones created as self were created in the current document(main.py) and self.ui were created in another document. The main widget is created in the ui file and then im dynamically adding these labels and frames within it.

Comment: @musicamante could you explain to me where I am adding same widgets to different layouts?

Comment: @musicamante how would I dynamically add buttons without overwriting? would I have to do something like: setObjectName(u"frame_12"+str(i)) ?

Comment: No, it wasn't granted that you used `self` and `self.ui` for that, that's why you should always provide a valid [mre]. No, in fact you're not adding the same widget to different layouts, but you *are* adding it twice (`self.ui.verticalLayout_15.addWidget(self.frame_12)` in the second loop) which is pointless. That said, it seems that you're making a lot of confusion on what attribute names are and how they are used, and also the purpose of Qt object names. And naming objects like you did is completely pointless and confusing, as those names are meaningless since you're always overwriting them.

Comment: When widgets are added to a parent, that parent takes *ownership* of them, so it's not necessary to keep a persistent reference on the python side (`self.someObject`); and even if it wasn't the case, overwriting the reference would have destroyed the previous object: if you do `self.a = A()` and then `self.a = B()` then the previous instance of `A` is destroyed. This doesn't happen when QObjects are reparented (for example, when they are added to a layout of a parent), so using a persistent reference as an instance attribute is completely pointless: just use a local variable.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to: 1. do some research on what classes and instances are, and how they and their attributes work; 2. try to put more efforts in using more appropriate names (there's no point in naming something `verticalLayout_15` if you're creating many instance of the same type, also only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not functions or variables/attributes); 3. use Qt object names for the proper reasons (for instance, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10009150) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26364295)), or don't use them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a grid layout instead of a horizontal layout:

```
    def loopCamFeed(self,n):
    self.frame_12 = QFrame(self.ui.webcamWidget)
    self.frame_12.setObjectName(u"frame_12")
    self.frame_12.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame_12.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.frame_12)
    self.grid_layout.setObjectName(u"grid_layout")
    for i in range(int(n)):
        self.label_5 = QLabel("hello",self.frame_12)
        self.label_5.setObjectName(u"label_5")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.label_5, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)
    self.ui.verticalLayout_15.addWidget(self.frame_12)
```

Comment: Hello @Medhat , thanks soo much for taking time to respond! I tried to apply your logic but it then doesnt apply dynamic labels equally into the widget. But I can try to review what you have shown and apply it. Just a question, is my approach incorrect? in the methodology for dynamically adding buttons?

Answer (score 0):

As Medhat mentioned, applying the GridLayout was the best solution.

I applied the following code:

```
def loopCamFeed(self,n):
    w = 0
    if n > 0:
        # if ( n % 2) == 0:
            
        for i in range(int(n)):
            if (i%2) == 0:
                w +=1                
            print(int(w / 2), (i%2))
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            self.label.setText("Screen " +str(i))
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: black5;")

            self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, (i%2) ,int(w),Qt.AlignHCenter )
```

This works perfectly! Thanks @Medhat